# Redisson - Is it possible to index arrays in Redisson Live Object based on member elements?

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I have objects that looks like

```java
@REntity
class Product {
@RId
String name;

@RIndex
String[] tags; // ["foo", "bar", ...]

...
}
```

How can I query all objects having `foo` as one of the tags using Redisson Live Object Service?